# Get response in JSON from API

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I am using HttpClient to consume an external API from an ASP.NET Web API controller. I am not using authentication, just a token, so I have:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) {

  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

  HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(endpoint);

}
```

I am getting the response always in XML format but I am sending header with "application/json".

Am I missing something it this is a problem with the external API?

What else can I try to get the response in JSON?

Comment: Have you tried to compose the similar request using any kind of tool like Advanced Rest Client or it's analog? Just to make sure that the server side can return json.

Comment: I tried Postman and I wasn't able to get JSON. What is strange is that in the API docs they have examples of responses and both XML and JSON are displayed.

Comment: They may ignore Accept header. It can be everything like ?format=json query parameter or something else. Try to contact API owners first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to the API developer(s) to respect the media type (application/json). It is possible for a developer to explicitly return XML when a client requests JSON (if they feel like trolling), though in this case it is probably just giving you the default format because they don't check the header value.

Check the docs or contact them directly to confirm they return data in JSON format and how to format the request to get JSON.

Answer (score -1):

You should set Accept: application/json as well as Content-Type: application/json.

Comment: Accept is for what the client can handle, a client setting Content-Type is only for any data uploaded from client to server, if client don't send data, then don't set Content-Type in the client.