# How to call API parallel processing instead passing one by one URI

Tags: c#, uri

Below is my working code, calling one by one URL.

URL examples : (https://XXXX.YYYY.com/API/ZZ/students/" + sAPIURL + "/applications" ) passing student code to API and getting API result. API has one argument which is student code.

```
foreach (var sAPIURL in APILIST)
{
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sAPIURL);
    // Set the Method property of the request to GET.
    request.Method = "GET";
    string sUserNamePassword = sUserName + ":" + sPassword;
    byte[] byteUserNamePassword = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sUserNamePassword);
    string encodedUserNamePassword = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteUserNamePassword);

    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedUserNamePassword);
    request.Headers.Add("aw-tenant-code", sAPIKEY);

    //HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();          
    System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    if (((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription + "\r\n" + "Link: " + sURL);
    }

    //if (!((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)response.statuscode = 200))
    //{
    //    //MsgBox(CType(response, System.Net.HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription);
    //    response.Close();
    //    return "Error";
    //}

    var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(dataStream);
    sJSONData = reader.ReadToEnd();

    // Close the Stream object.
    dataStream.Close();
    reader.Close();
    response.Close();

    return sJSONData;  
}
```

Comment: [How to: Write a simple Parallel.ForEach loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 1):

Try to run a parallel task, something like this

```
  var Maintasks = new[]
                   {
                   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => apiCall()),
                   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => apiCall()),
                   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => apiCall())
                   };
  Task.WaitAll(Maintasks);
```

Comment: Thank you so much .I'm new to c#, if possible could you explain in detail also new to calling API

Comment: instead of apiCall() add your request

Comment: Thanks! How can i get the value which is return the API.
in your case apicall() will return the json data.

Answer (score 1):

You can make something like this with HttpClient:

```
        using var client = new HttpClient(); // init client

        // set headers

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
            "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(
                System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                    $"{username}:{password}"))); 

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("aw-tenant-code", $"{key}");

        // generate list of requests
        var list = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) // count of parallel requests or other GET requests
        {
            // add requests to the list of tasks
            list.Add(client.GetAsync("https://www.google.com/"));
        }

        // all requests finished
        await Task.WhenAll(list);

        foreach (var task in list)
        {
            // get result per each request
            var result = await task;
        }
```

Or if you want to use HttpRequestMessage

```
        var list = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();

        var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri("some uri"),
            Headers = {
                // headers
            }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            list.Add(client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(list);

        foreach (var task in list)
        {
            var result = await task;

            if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                // do something
            }

            // to read the content as string
            var stringResult = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // to deserialize the content as some entity
            var someEntity = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyCustomObject>();
        }
```

*Note: your method should be **async***

Comment: I'm using second one, I can able to see Status code. But I dont know , how to check the return value which is API returns.

Comment: You can read data from the response (HttpResponseMessage if you made a request with HttpClient).

Example: 

// after ->
var result = await task;

// you can read data as string ->

var stringContentResult = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

// or if you expect some entity you can write you own class and deserialize content as this class ->
var someEntityResult = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyCustomEntity>();

Comment: .Thank you so much . i got it...
I want in json format , so have added client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
Also got it in json

Comment: You can use this code: client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); _____
But did you check the API? Have you tried to make the same request via Postman or tool like this? Just to be sure that API is able to return JSON response

Comment: Maybe this link can help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890261/get-response-in-json-from-api

Comment: 1) JSON issue solved.
2) Getting another exception, When am passing more than 1000 URI, am getting following error."An exception of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code"
"Additional information: A task was canceled." , Could you please help on this.

Comment: Hm, I think it's because of your API (the requests dead by timeout so you get the error). Because your API cannot process too many requests at the same time.

Comment: Thanks Mike Polo. Now I'm planning to pass 50 records at a time.

Comment: Event though if am passing 50 by 50 records, getting same error. is there any way to close, the opened request(httpRequestMessage ) ? before passing next 50 records.? could you please help me on this.

Comment: Try to wast the result: of 50 tasks -> var result = await Task.WhenAll(list).Also, you can create a method like "sendRequestsAsync(int count)" which has a parameter: count of requests. Call it in the loop: for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) { var result = await sendRequestsAsync(50); }. Try this approach. If it will not help you need to increase performance in your API because requests wait too long

Comment: I achieved it using Timeout method. Thank you so much. :)